# How to create a dataset in python

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, dataset, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I would like to create my own dataset similar to *digits* from [scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html). I know that a dataset is a dictionary-like object with all the data and some metadata about the set.  What im looking for is to create the dataset from some images, example:

[image]

I am looking for some *wiki* or documentation on how to build a python dataset from scratch.

Comment: gather your data, tag it, publish it.

Comment: @lejlot can you expand you comment. Not sure what you mean by tag the data and publish it.

Comment: there is nothing to elaborate about, you do it by hand

Comment: @lejlot Sure I get that part but how do you build the actual dataset to use later like in the case of sklearn learn library " from sklearn import digits". Is there any documentation on how to build this type of datasets?

Comment: no, there is not as it is extremely basic - it is just a dictionary, a basic python data structure, without any standard or rules

Comment: I see, thanks for the note. I have experience working with R although they have similar datatypes, I wasnt sure if there is a different way to do this in python.